# Comparing elements in list to every element in a list-of-lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I'm trying to compare an element from one list to every element in a list-of-lists.

```
hsdr_machine_one=['P#1', 'P#2', ...]
hsdr_machine_two=[...]
hsdr_machine_three=[...]

hsff_machine_four=['P#4', 'P#5', ...]
hsff_machine_five=['P#6', ...]
hsff_machine_six=[...]

hsdr_machines_list=[hsdr_machine_one, hsdr_machine_two, hsdr_machine_three]
hsff_machines_list=[hsff_machine_four, hsff_machine_five, hsff_machine_six]

part_number_combinations = []
for part_number in itertools.product(*hsdr_machines_list):
    part_number_combinations = [part_number[0]] + [part_number[1]]
    print part_number_combinations
```

I know this code isn't going to get me there, it's just what I was messing around with in `itertools`. I was using `product(hsdr_machine_one, hsff_machine_four)` earlier with success for comparing just two machines. But now I want to try and do it all at once.

Output would be:

```
P#1, P#4
P#1, P#5
P#1, P#6
P#2, P#4
P#2, P#5 ...
```

And then it would move onto comparing `hsdr_machine_two` vs. `hsff_machine_four`, `five`, and `six`.

Comment: Are you trying to find matching machines between the lists?

Comment: Nitpick: a `set` cannot contain a `list` (or any other mutable type). You're looking for comparing elements in list to every element in a list of lists.

Comment: Nope. Each machine has 6-12 parts it can run. I am trying to figure out if an operator can run two machines. The parts vary in size, cycle times, packs, etc.. So I just need to generate every possible pairing between the two machine groups to run through my work functions.

Comment: Thanks Zwer, nitpicking is great. I'm new to coding so any chance to learn something is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create combinations of sublists using `itertools.products`, then take products of pairs using items from two sublists at a time:

```
for hsdr, hsff in itertools.product(hsdr_machines_list, hsff_machines_list):
    for pt1, pt2 in itertools.product(hsdr, hsff):
         print pt1, pt2
```

Comment: Thank you, tried this one as well and it also worked.

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the nested lists and then look at the Cartesian product of the elements.

```
hsdr_flat = sum(hsdr_machines_list, [])
hsff_flat = sum(hsff_machines_list, [])

for hsdr, hsff in itertools.product(hsdr_flat, hsff_flat):
    print hsdr, hsff
```